# How can I set a custom menu shortcut for Mark as Played in the macOS Podcasts app?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, podcasts, macos-bigsur

I did find the documentation at:

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-keyboard-shortcuts-for-apps-mchlp2271/mac

and was able to set a menu shortcut for the menu option.

[image]

However, the shortcut open shows up dimmed in the menu and does not work.

[image: menu option]

I am using BigSur.

How can I have this work?

Comment: Did you try any other key combo? I've never seen a shortcut greyed out if the menu item was active [but I've never used Big Sur]

Comment: Yes, I’ve tried a few. Should try more.

Comment: @Tetsujin Tried many more. no luck. If you happen across a key combination that will work, I would be interested.

Comment: I can't test it empirically, I have neither Big Sur nor the Podcast app. Sorry.

Comment: I just got a chance to look at this.  I think the menu you're showing is a contextual menu, not a menubar-menu.  I didn't know that you could apply keyboard shortcuts to contextual menu items!  Well, maybe you can't, based on your results.  Can you try a different menu item in your pic, like Save Episode, and maybe a VERY unique key-combo, like Ctrl-Opt-Cmd-U (never seen that one used before)?

Comment: BTW, this question is even more relevant now that iOS 14.5 is out, with the updated Podcasts app.  If you have previously "deleted" episodes from a show without listening to them, they're now back as (sort-of) unplayed episodes.  Using the macOS Podcasts app is the most efficient way to make all of them as played, but selecting a bunch of episodes at once, and using this "Mark as Played" menu item!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the experiments that I've tried, this is not possible.

As I said in a comment above, I didn't even know that you could assign a shortcut to a contextual menu item.  I tried it, and I can get it to appear as in your pic, and I can assign a VERY unique key combo to it.  But the key-combo just doesn't work.  I even tried with another contextual menu item:

[image: CM]

It's not visible in my pic, but that key-combo is also greyed like your F1 example.  I moved this key-combo to another "real" menu item (Half Speed), and it works there.

My conclusion: contextual menu items can't really be assigned keyboard shortcuts.  I tested in the TV app as well, same results.

I even went a bit farther, looking in Automator and the AppleScript, and there are no "dictionaries" for scripting the Podcast app.

I'm afraid this isn't possible (yet) with this app.

Answer (score 0):

> "My conclusion: contextual menu items can't really be assigned
> keyboard shortcuts."

I also tried this some time ago for other contextual menu items and wasn't successful, except for one case: "Show package contents" in Finder. Although the keys are not displayed in the contextual menu, it works, for apps and Blu-ray BDMV directories, but not for pkg, who don't have that context menu item anymore...